# Word SelectionChange event

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VBA in MS Word (using **Developer => Visual Basic** option)

and I try to capture the event which fires when I scroll to different page in the document (whether by mouse or by keyboard)
I tried using different event names (based on what I found on the internet) but nothing catches

```
Private Sub ThisDocument_SelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    ' Check if the user is scrolling (i.e., changing the selection)
    ' and display a message box.
    
    MsgBox "You are scrolling the document."
    
End Sub
Private Sub ThisDocument_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    ' Check if the user is scrolling (i.e., changing the selection)
    ' and display a message box.
    
    MsgBox "You are scrolling the document."
    
End Sub
Private Sub Document_SelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    ' Check if the user is scrolling (i.e., changing the selection)
    ' and display a message box.
    
    MsgBox "You are scrolling the document."
    
End Sub

Private Sub Document_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    ' Check if the user is scrolling (i.e., changing the selection)
    ' and display a message box.
    MsgBox "You are scrolling the document."
    
End Sub
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Hi I tried a macro in which I scroll the page, and it gives me the following code:  ```Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdScreen, Count:=3
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdScreen, Count:=2
End Sub```
But its a method, not an event,  I need an event which catches these actions, preferably when the page changes for any reason

Comment: There is no event for that. Maybe you can explain what exactly you are trying to do when the user scrolls?

Comment: I want to change the background of the document for different pages in the document, So If I am in page 1-10 the background will be blue, and when I am in page 11-20 the background will be yelllow etc. I cannot do different background for every page, only for the whole document, so I want to trick the document to change background colors based on which page I am looking on at the moment

Comment: You cannot control the background color of each page individually either. Sounds like you would need a routine to print each page individually, changing the background color of the whole document between each page print.

Comment: I know, that's why I want to know which page I am on in order to hadle the backgroud of the whole document based on that page

Comment: So there is no way to raise an event to know which page I am working at the moment?

Comment: You can tell where the cursor is, but that doesn't mean you are viewing that page.

Comment: Is there an event for cursor change?

Comment: Not an event, no.

Comment: Maybe you can find something to help you following this path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word

Comment: I will look at it. Thank you !